# How to add DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive in sudoers.d file?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, go, debian, sudoers

I am automating dpkg-sig installation for one of my project purpose. Now I want to install it noninteractive way.

I have added the following in a file inside /etc/sudoers.d/

```
Cmnd_Alias DPKGSIG_INSTALL = /usr/bin/apt install -y dpkg-sig, \
                            /bin/apt install -y dpkg-sig
abc ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: DPKGSIG_INSTALL
Defaults:abc !requiretty
```

I am trying to install dpkg-sig using my golang code like this:

```
installDpkgSig := "/usr/bin/sudo DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt install -o Dpkg::Options::=--force-confold -y dpkg-sig"
executor.cmd = *exec.Command("bash", "-c", installDpkgSig)
```

It is not able to install it. Getting the following error:

```
sudo: sorry, you are not allowed to set the following environment variables: DEBIAN_FRONTEND
```

But when I remove *DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive* part from the installation command, it is working fine.
How can run the installation noninteractive way?

Comment: I'm unsure if there are any security/other ramifications, but you could maybe briefly try `/usr/bin/sudo env DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive ...`

Comment: Won't it change the env variable for the system as a whole rather than for that bash session?

Comment: @SouravBhattacharjee No.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to involve Bash (it might even open up for more bugs); just set the environment variable for the command:

```
cmd := exec.Command("sudo", "apt-get", "install", "-o", "Dpkg::Options::=--force-confold", "-y", "dpkg-sig")
cmd.Env = append(os.Environ(), "DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive")
err := cmd.Run()
```

---

<sup>(Also, use `apt-get`, not `apt`, for non-interactive tasks.)</sup>

Comment: Any reason for using apt-get and not apt?
What bugs can it involve using Bash?

Comment: Regarding `apt`: It’s not designed for ‘non-human’ use; its behaviour might change. See [`apt(8)`](https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/apt/apt.8.en.html#SCRIPT_USAGE). `apt-get` has a stable API. Regarding Bash: It just introduces more room for errors, e.g. syntax errors like unintended expansions, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Finally able to fix this problem. It doesn't require any changes on the /etc/sudoers.d/ file.

Modified the above code like the following and it worked.

```
installDpkgSig := "export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive && /usr/bin/sudo apt install -o Dpkg::Options::=--force-confold -y dpkg-sig"
executor.cmd = *exec.Command("bash", "-c", installDpkgSig)
```

And as the bash session finishes *DEBIAN_FRONTEND* will be set to default.